# Should I use "what for" or "for what" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> Speaker A: Time to wake up.
>
> Speaker B: **What for/For what?**
>
> Speaker A: To go shopping.

Should it be *what for* or *for what*? And why?

Comment: 'What for?' is the most common usage, although 'For what?' is still correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What for" sounds more like everyday speaking English. However, "For what" delivers a somewhat grumpy tone.

Either way fine. Up to the writer on subtle tone or feeling expressed by the sleeper.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's appropriate to use ''for what?''rather than the opposite.
The complete dialogue is: 
**A:**  It is time for you to wake up.
**B:** 【Why】 should i get up for now?
**A:**  Cause we'r going to go shopping.
As you can see, the original is asking the reason, 
and for means giving or ''because of sth.''(there is always an object following it); thus,after narrow down, for is put at the first word not what. 
If you'd like to put what at the beginning, it should be a complete sense. i dont understand the deeper of this,perhaps, this is the rule that only the first one would know why he/she created and used in this way...
And, hope someone can explain in detail..

Comment: What for? and Why? are equivalent when asking for a reason.